# Regex not working correctly - String must contain a number and a string separated by a white space

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm having some troubles with a regex expression.
I need the fourth field to be enabled when the third one is filled with a number and a string separated by a white space, but for some reason I can't make it work.

This is the pattern: `\d+ *?.*? .*`
Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Aleja_Ro/2kq3amnr/1/):

```js
function validateStreetNumber(variable){
    var reg=new RegExp('/\d+ *?.*? .*');
    console.log(reg);
    var compare=reg.test(variable);
    return compare;
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#state').prop('disabled',true);
    $('#address').prop('disabled',true);
    $('#number').prop('disabled',true);

    $('#city').on("input",function(){
        var value=$(this).val();

        if(value==''){
          $('#state').prop('disabled',true);
          $('#address').prop('disabled',true);
          $('#number').prop('disabled',true);
        }

        else{
          $('#state').prop('disabled',false);
        }
    });
    $('#state').on("change",function(){
        var value=$(this).val();

        if(value=='select'){
          $('#address').prop('disabled',true);
          $('#number').prop('disabled',true);
        }

        else{
          $('#address').prop('disabled',false);
        }
    });
    $('#address').on("input",function(){
        var value=$(this).val();
        var exp=validateStreetNumber(value);

        if(!exp){
          $('#number').prop('disabled',true);
        }

        else if(exp){
          $('#number').prop('disabled',false);
        }
 });
});
```

```css
input, select{
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#" id="test" name="test">
    <input type="text" id="city" name="city" maxlength="100" /><br>
    <select id="state" name="state">
      <option value="select">Select</option>
      <option value="aragua">Aragua</option>
      <option value="carabobo">Carabobo</option>
      <option value="miranda">Miranda</option>
      <option value="zulia">Zulia</option>
      <option value="bolivar">Bolívar</option>
    </select><br>
    <input type="text" id="address" name="address" maxlength="100"/><br>
    <input type="text" id="number" name="number" maxlength="8"/><br>
</form>
```

(Sorry for my english)

Comment: What kind of number? Digits? Like `12 x#$%`? Or `1.34-e3 (<fff33>)`? Try just `var reg=/^\d+\s/;`

Comment: Digits. Like 12, 53526, 123 or something like that...

Comment: Check https://jsfiddle.net/beg6pxgt/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex - `new RegExp('/\d+ *?.*? .*')` - evaluates to `/\/d+ *?.*? .*/` regex: a `/`, followed with one or more `d` letters, a space zero or more times, any char zero or more times, a space and any 0+ chars. The problem is that you have `/` at the start and an improperly escaped `d` (you need 2 backslashes in the constructor notation).

You need to use the following regex:

```
var reg=/^\d+\s/;
```

It checks if a string starts with 1+ digits and a whitespace after them.

There is no point adding `.*` or `.*?` since you are only interested in what is at the beginning of the string.

**Details**:

- `^` - string start
- `\d+` - 1 or more digits
- `\s` - a whitespace.

Comment: Works like a charm! You saved me. Thank you!!

Comment: Wiktor, how come var reg=new RegExp('^\d+\s'); doesn't work and the literal reg = /^\d+\s/; works?

Comment: @Canolyb1:  A backslash is an escaping symbol in C strings, to be able to use `\n` for newline, `\r` for carriage return, etc. To write a literal backslash, you need to use 2 backslashes, `"\\"`. In regex literals defined inside `/.../` the backslashes are treated as literal backslashes. `/^\d+\s/` = `new RegExp('^\\d+\\s')`

Comment: Thank you! completely forgot that the backslashes need to be escaped.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
var reg=new RegExp('/\d+ *?.*? .*');
```

to

```
var reg=new RegExp('\d+ *?.*? .*');
```

There is no need to put the / when your using the RegEx object constructor.

Also if you just want any number separated by a space and followed by a string of any character (including space) you should simply use:
\d+ .*

Comment: For some reason it still doesn't work... :/ for some reason when I type digits, the fourth field doesn't enable, but if I type letters and then hit the spacebar, the field enables. I can't fin the error :/

Comment: Convert it to RegEx literal:
like this: 
var reg=/\d+ .*/; This works, I'm not sure why the constructor doesn't

Comment: No, that won't do. See my answer for the correct solution. I also explain what is "wrong" with `new RegExp('\d')`.